How should I modify the rust program to run it?
this code can not run
fn main() {
    let a = 2;
    let b = 3;
    println!("{}",sum1(&a,&b));
  }
fn sum1<T:std::ops::Add<Output = T>>(a:&T,b:&T)->T{
  a + b
}

use (a:T,b:T) can run,and the following code can run too
fn main() {
    let a = 2;
    let b = 3;
    println!("{}",sum1(&a,&b));
}
  
fn sum1(a:&i32,b:&i32)->T{
  a + b
}


The problem is that you define the check if std::ops::Add is supported for T but not for &T.
To allow the usage of &T you would do this:
fn sum1<T>(a: &T, b: &T) -> T
where
    for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    a + b
}

Alternatively you could use - while not fully equivalent - this:
fn sum1<'a, T>(a: &'a T, b: &'a T) -> T
where
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    a + b
}

The second solution would only work with references derived from the arguments, so not for setups like this:
fn sum1<'a, T>(a: impl AsRef<T>, b: &'a T) -> T
where
    &'a T: std::ops::Add<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    a.as_ref() + b
}


Note: These are not equivalent and the second variant (without a HRTB) only works with references derived from the arguments, not with ones created inside the function.
